# Is there a way to pass dplyr's `do` function a vector of additional arguments?

Tags: r, dplyr

I was curious if there was a way to pass dplyr's `do` function a vector of additional arguments which would be applied to each group in turn? Consider, for example, if we wanted to group the `mtcars` dataset by its `cyl` variable and apply the `head` function to the resulting groups (one for 4, 6, and 8 respectively) with n = 1 for the 4 group, n = 2 for the 6 group, and n = 3 for the 8 group, combining the final results in a single dataframe.

I can accomplish this using `mapply` as follows:

```
temp <- mtcars %>% 
  split(mtcars$cyl) %>%
  mapply(FUN = head, x = ., n = 1:3, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
rbind(temp[[1]], temp[[2]], temp[[3]])
```

I was curious if there was an equivalent way of doing this with dplyr? I got as far as below, but was stymied as to how to pass `head` an additional argument representing the number of rows we would like to select:

```
# only selects first row of each group
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(head(x = ., n = 1)))

# throws an error because n expects a single number
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(head(x = ., n = 1:3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also possible without grouping at all,

```
mtcars %>% arrange(cyl) %>% slice(rep(c(0, which(diff(cyl)>0)), 1:3) + sequence(1:3))

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 3 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 4 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 5 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 6 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

To answer your question about `do` more directly, because of the way it is implemented (evaluating the expression in a loop through the subsets), one way to make your `head` function work, would be to have it increment a variable everytime it is called.

```
## Define a function that increments a variable each time it is called
heads <- (function() { n <- 0; function(dat) { n <<- n+1; dat[1:n, ] } })()

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(heads(.))
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 3 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 4 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 5 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 6 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

Comment: this is exactly along the lines of what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> if we wanted to group the mtcars dataset by its cyl variable and apply the head function to the resulting groups (one for 4, 6, and 8 respectively) with n = 1 for the 4 group, n = 2 for the 6 group, and n = 3 for the 8 group

First, formalize this notion in a data.frame:

```
heads = data.frame(cyl=c(4,6,8), n = 1:3)
```

Then you can merge it in:

```
mtcars %>% left_join(heads) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice(seq(first(n)))

#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     n
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (int)
# 1  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1     1
# 2  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4     2
# 3  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4     2
# 4  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2     3
# 5  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4     3
# 6  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3     3
```

I would also consider dodging extra parentheses with

```
... %>% slice(n %>% first %>% seq)
```

`do` exists only as a hack when the other dplyr functions aren't up to the job, and should be avoided.

Comment: I really like the idea of encapsulating the additional arguments in a data frame and using a left join to combine them with the original data frame. But I think this answer is slightly off the point, and I believe it's because I did not provide a good example. My actual problem was that I had a data frame representing patient information and I wanted to run a simulation on the different groups with different arguments. I was able to do this with `mapply` but was curious if I could do this with `do` since I use `dplyr` frequently. I realize my `head` example didn't capture my intent though.

Comment: @JeromeFroelich I don't really follow. Everything that can be done to different groups with `split ... do` can be done far better with `group_by` in terms of speed and being idiomatic, right? Your `mapply` approach isn't really clear to me -- do you write your args in for each group by hand inside the `mapply` call? Anyway, if you think there's a better way to frame the problem, I'd suggest posting it as a new question. However, if folks can't distinguish it from this one, it might not be received well ("didn't you just ask this?" etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This was really more of a thought experiment question than an actual problem, but it seems to have generated a good discussion. The way I used `mapply` was like so: `df %>% split(df$group_variable) %>% mapply(FUN = simulate_function, x = ., group_specific_args)` I was primarily interested if this could also be done with `group_by...do`, and the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191821/is-there-a-way-to-pass-dplyrs-do-function-a-vector-of-additional-arguments/33195020#33195020) by @Bunk is aligned with what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I bet there's a more elegant way to do this, but:

```
group_index = 
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_indices

mtcars %>%
  mutate(group_index = group_index) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  slice(group_index %>% first %>% seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work. this solution is specific to the mtcars example but something like this may work in your case .
it involves creating your own function that has conditional statements based off the column you are grouping off of:

```
head_custom <- function(df, n){

    if(df$cyl == 4){
    ans <- head(df, n[1])
    }

    if(df$cyl == 6){
    ans <- head(df, n[2])
    }

    if(df$cyl == 8){
    ans <- head(df, n[3])
    }

    return(ans)
}

mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
do(head_custom(., n = 1:3))
```

Comment: You could put the `if()` statement in the `n` argument, like `head_custom <- function(df, n) head(df, n[if(df$cyl[1] == 4) 1 else if(df$cyl[1] == 6) 2 else 3])`.  This should also take care of your warnings problem.  Note the subsets on `cyl`.  You were getting tons of warnings. Also check `help("==")`, as it should really be avoided in `if()` statements if possible

Comment: I was giving a generic example of using conditional statements in the 
"do" function. I think the OP's problem is much different, but the mtcars example was just to show using conditionals in the function as a way to execute the "do" function with more than one parameter.

Comment: You could also fix the warnings by creating: 
    `cyl.i <- unique(df$cyl)` at the top of the function, and then checking `if(cyl.i == 4){...}`

Comment: that is an interesting tip on not using "==" in a conditional, that is good to know.